# Why can I not use variable? [Kotlin]

Tags: selenium, kotlin

I am a Java developer who just switched to Kotlin and I haven't completely unterstood it yet.
I cant understand why I cant use my obj in the other methods in my following code..?
I use kotlin on IntelliJ in combination with selneium(which shouldnt really make a difference, should it?)
I tried putting it out of the init method but that didnt work either...
Thanks in advance.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

class MapsDriver()
{

    init {
        var obj : ChromeDriver = ChromeDriver()
    }

    fun convertToGmURL(string : String) : String{
        var string_trimmed : String = ""
        string.forEach {
            if(it == ' '){
                string_trimmed += "+"
            }
            else{
                string_trimmed += it
            }
        }
        return string_trimmed
    }

    fun searchMaps(search : String){

        val searchConverted : String  = convertToGmURL(search)

        obj.get("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$searchConverted")

    }

    fun getXpath(Xpath : String) : String{
        loop@while(true) {
            try {
                var result = obj.findElementByXPath(Xpath)
                return result.text
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException : Exception){
                continue@loop
            }
        }
    }

    fun getResultName(resultNumber : Int) : String{
        val convertedIndex : Int = (resultNumber * 2) + 1
        var result : String = getXpath("//*[@id=\"pane\"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[$convertedIndex]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h3/span")
        return result
    }

    fun getAllResults(){
        Thread.sleep(1_000)
        val amountIndexes = getXpath("//*[@id=\"pane\"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span/span[2]")
        val amountIndexesInt : Int = amountIndexes.toInt()
        val resultsName : Array<String> = Array(amountIndexesInt){getResultName(it)}

        resultsName.forEach { println(it) }
    }

}

fun main(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/josef/Java/cdriver/chromedriver")
    val md : MapsDriver = MapsDriver()
    md.searchMaps("Autohaus Muenchen")
    md.getAllResults()
}
```

Comment: ``I cant understand why I cant use my obj in the other methods in my following code..?``` - What do you mean? What are you seeing?

Comment: It's related to the scope of the variable.  You can declare it outside and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `obj` is a variable local to the `init` method, so it's equivalent to the following Java code:

```
class MapsDriver {
    public MapsDriver() {
        ChromeDriver obj = new ChromeDriver();
        // you can't use obj anywhere else as it's local to the constructor
    }
}
```

If you want `obj` to be an instance variable, then you should do something like:

```
class MapsDriver {
    private val obj = ChromeDriver() // instance variable, no need for init block in this case
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have another problem, maybe you could help me with that, too?

Comment: sure, but if it's related to a different concept/problem I guess creating a new question is better as it can be indexed and searched more effectively